# Access: Hiding the header on the first page of a section works initially...and then fails. Any thoughts?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I am using code based on widely used methods described here and elsewhere to suppress a page header on the first page of a report section in Access 2016. The code works fine for the first three sections but then removes the header on the second page rather than the first and gets the section page count wrong, including the first page of the following section in the total. If I eliminate the .visible=False statement, the section page numbering is fine, so it feels like removing the header section is messing up the pagination in a way that Access is not adjusting for? Has anyone else had this problem and if so, is there a solution?

Many thanks in advance

Simon

```
Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Me.Pages = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve GrpArrayPage(Me.Page + 1)
        ReDim Preserve GrpArrayPages(Me.Page + 1)
        GrpNameCurrent = Me!txtCompany_name2
        If GrpNameCurrent = GrpNamePrevious Then
            GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) = GrpArrayPage(Me.Page - 1) + 1
            GrpPages = GrpArrayPage(Me.Page)
            For i = Me.Page - ((GrpPages) - 1) To Me.Page
                GrpArrayPages(i) = GrpPages
            Next i
        Else
            GrpPage = 1
            GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) = GrpPage
            GrpArrayPages(Me.Page) = GrpPage
        End If
    Else

        Me!txtCheck = "Group Page " & GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) & " of " & GrpArrayPages(Me.Page)
        If GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) = 1 Then
                    Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = False
            'Me.PageFooterSection.Visible = True

        Else
            Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = True
            'Me.PageFooterSection.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
    GrpNamePrevious = GrpNameCurrent
End Sub
```

Comment: Formatting reports can be fun ;( Section means group?No group-headers? Show an inage of design-view or export report with SaveAsText- Add watches, breakpoints to cjeck count is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions- I was on hols, hence the slow acknowledgement. There was nothing wrong with the counting so I think it was simply Access's inability to repaginate when sections of a certain height are made invisible. The solution was to place a white box over the relevant section and toggle the visibility as required.